# How to find the sum of a ASCII value in a file to find the max number of ASCII and to print out the name of the highest sum of ASCII value

Tags: python

Here is the code I'm working with

```
def ascii_sum():
    x = 0
    infile = open("30075165.txt","r")
    for line in infile:
        return sum([ord(x) for x in line])
    infile.close()
```

This code only prints out the first ASCII value in the file not the max ASCII value

Comment: you can't expand on your previous question?

Comment: I already have a solution to this in the update of your previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1292630/how-to-open-a-file-and-find-the-longest-length-of-a-line-and-then-print-it-out/1292676#1292676 I bet this also answeres your NEXT question also.

Answer (score 1):

```
max(open(fname), key=lambda line: sum(ord(i) for i in line))
```

Comment: +1 and if he wants the line number he can do: max(enumerate(open(fname)), key=lambda (i, line): sum(ord(i) for i in line))

Answer (score 1):

This is a snippet from an answer to one to of your [previous questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1292630/how-to-open-a-file-and-find-the-longest-length-of-a-line-and-then-print-it-out/1292676#1292676)

```
def get_file_data(filename):
    def ascii_sum(line):
        return sum([ord(x) for x in line])
    def word_count(line):
        return len(line.split(None))

    filedata = [{'line': line, 
                 'line_len': len(line), 
                 'ascii_sum': ascii_sum(line), 
                 'word_count': word_count(line)}
                for line in open(filename, 'r')]

    return filedata

afile = r"C:\Tmp\TestFile.txt"
file_data = get_file_data(afile)

print max(file_data, key=lambda line: line['line_len']) # Longest Line
print max(file_data, key=lambda line: line['ascii_sum']) # Largest ASCII sum
print max(file_data, key=lambda line: line['word_count']) # Most Words
```